# ReactJS - Handle multiples exports in a file + withRouter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, module, react-router-dom

I'm currently working on a web project using NodeJS and ReactJS. I wanted to have two components in a single file because they will use the same pieces of information. One of the component is using withRouter to handle the "this.props.history.push". Since I don't know the syntax to deal with my 2 conditions (withRouter + double export) I'm looking for your help. 
I get the error :

```
Failed to compile
./src/App.js
284:83-110 './components/Dnoc_cvat.js' does not contain an export named 'Dnoc_cvat_bouton_withRouter'.
```

And in my App.js I wrote :

```
import {Dnoc_cvat_bouton_withRouter} from './components/Dnoc_cvat.js'
```

Dnoc_cvat.js :

```
import React from 'react'
import {withRouter}from 'react-router-dom';

class Dnoc_cvat extends React.Component {
   render() {
   return( 
       <h3> DNOC - CVAT </h3>
         )
   }
}

class Dnoc_cvat_bouton extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
       super(props);
        this.handleClick=this.handleClick.bind(this);
   }

   handleClick(){
       this.props.history.push('/DNOC/CVAT');
   }

   render() {
   return( 
       <div className='component-button' onClick={this.handleClick} >
            <p>Hello world</p>
       </div>
         )
      }
   }

module.exports={
   Dnoc_cvat:Dnoc_cvat,
   Dnoc_cvat_bouton_withRouter:withRouter(Dnoc_cvat_bouton)
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`module.exports`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_exports) works only in Node.js.

For the browser, you will need the following [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export) syntax:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

export class Dnoc_cvat extends React.Component {
  ...
}

class Dnoc_cvat_bouton extends React.Component {
  ...
}

export const Dnoc_cvat_bouton_withRouter = withRouter(Dnoc_cvat_bouton)
```

Comment: I tried solutions like that but without the const. I'm very glad it actually works. Thanks a lot !